# Java 2-D Arrays - Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: java, arrays, random

This tic tac toe game is user vs computer based.
For this assignment, I'm supposed to fill in the missing pieces, which is just finishing up the main and moveAI methods(the other methods are already preset, I just need to call them); there is comments provided where I need to add code to make this tic tac toe game work. I believe that my main method that I have is almost done except for the 2 empty lines under the comments, I'm not sure what they mean by that and also I'm currently stuck on getting my moveAI method to work. This is where I'm supposed to generate random places where the computer will move after I put an X somewhere. I'm not sure how to write something that will check to make sure the spot where the computer moves is available and not already taken by the user. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TicTacToeGame
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner ( System.in );
        char[][] board = new char[ 3 ][ 3 ];
        int x, y = -1;
        char winner = 'N';
            // Initialize the board to spaces
          //  boolean noWinner = true;
        char player = 'X';
        for (int r = 0; x < board.length(); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < board.length(); c++)
            {
                board[r][c] = ' ';
            }
        }

        // Print the game board        
        printBoard(board);

        // Keep playing while the game isn't finished
        while (winner == 'N')
        {
            while (x < 0 && x >2 && y <0 && y > 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the row and column, separated by spaces: ");
                x = in.nextInt();
                y = in.nextInt();
            }


            // Get the location from the user and validate it


            // Mark the position in the board according to the user's specified location


            // Print the board after the user plays
            printBoard(board);
            // Check to see if the game is finished. If it is, break out of the loop.

            // Have the AI make a move
            moveAI(board);
            // Print the board after the AI plays
            printBoard(board);

            // Check to see who the winner is
            winner =  checkWinner(board);
        }
        // If the winner is 'X' or 'O', print that, otherwise, it is a tie
        if (winner == 'X')
            System.out.println("X is the winner!");
        else if (winner == 'O')
            System.out.println("O is the winner!");
        else
            System.out.println("Tie");


    }
    /**
     * Makes a move for the AI, and marks the board with an 'O'.
     *
     * @param   board   The game board
     */
 public static void moveAI ( char[][] board )
    {
        int x,y = -1;
        Random r = new Random();
        x = r.nextInt(3);
        y = r.nextInt(3);
        boolean open = false;

        // Validate that the random location generated is valid.
        while (x < 0 && x >2 && y < 0 && y > 2)
        {
            x = r.nextInt(3);
            y = r.nextInt(3);
        }
        while (open == false)
        {
          if (board[r][c] != ' ')
            while (x < 0 && x >2 && y < 0 && y > 2)
            {
                x = r.nextInt(3);
                y = r.nextInt(3);
            }
        }
        }

            // Keep recalculating the location if the one generated is not
           // if (board[r][c] != ' ')
            //{


            // an empty space.
            System.out.print(" ");

            // Be sure to mark the position in the board with an 'O'
            board[][]=in.nextInt(3) + 'O';
        }

        /**
         * Prints out the tic-tac-toe board
         *
         * @param   board   The game board
         */
 public static void printBoard ( char[][] board )
        {
            // Box drawing unicode characters:

            char a = '\u250c';              // U+250C : top-left
            char b = '\u2510';              // U+2510 : top-right
            char c = '\u2514';              // U+2514 : bottom-left
            char d = '\u2518';              // U+2518 : bottom-right
            char e = '\u252c';              // U+252C : top-vertical-connector
            char f = '\u2534';              // U+2534 : bottom-vertical-connector
            char g = '\u251c';              // U+251C : left-horizontal-connector
            char h = '\u2524';              // U+2524 : right-horizontal-connector
            char i = '\u253c';              // U+253C : center plus sign connector
            char j = '\u2500';              // U+2500 : horizontal
            char k = '\u2502';              // U+2502 : vertical
            String l = j + "" + j + "" + j; // Three horizontals

            // Print out the game board

            System.out.printf ( "\n    0   1   2\n" +
                    "  %c%s%c%s%c%s%c\n" +
                    "0 %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n" +
                    "  %c%s%c%s%c%s%c\n" +
                    "1 %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n" +
                    "  %c%s%c%s%c%s%c\n" +
                    "2 %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n" +
                    "  %c%s%c%s%c%s%c\n\n",
                    a, l, e, l, e, l, b,
                    k, board[0][0], k, board[0][1], k, board[0][2], k,
                    g, l, i, l, i, l, h,
                    k, board[1][0], k, board[1][1], k, board[1][2], k,
                    g, l, i, l, i, l, h,
                    k, board[2][0], k, board[2][1], k, board[2][2], k,
                    c, l, f, l, f, l, d );

        }

        /**
         * Checks the result of the game
         *
         * @param   board   The game board
         * @return          'X' if 'X' is the winner
         *                  'O' if 'O' is the winner
         *                  'T' if the game is a tie
         *                  'N' if the game isn't finished
         */
 public static char checkWinner( char[][] board )
        {
            if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[0][1] == 'X' && board[0][2] == 'X' ||       // Check row 0
                    board[1][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X' ||   // Check row 1
                    board[2][0] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X' ||   // Check row 2
                    board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][0] == 'X' && board[2][0] == 'X' ||   // Check col 0
                    board[0][1] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X' ||   // Check col 1
                    board[0][2] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X' ||   // Check col 2
                    board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X' ||   // Check diag \
                    board[0][2] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][0] == 'X' ||   // Check diag /

                    board[0][0] == 'x' && board[0][1] == 'x' && board[0][2] == 'x' ||   // Check row 0
                    board[1][0] == 'x' && board[1][1] == 'x' && board[1][2] == 'x' ||   // Check row 1
                    board[2][0] == 'x' && board[2][1] == 'x' && board[2][2] == 'x' ||   // Check row 2
                    board[0][0] == 'x' && board[1][0] == 'x' && board[2][0] == 'x' ||   // Check col 0
                    board[0][1] == 'x' && board[1][1] == 'x' && board[2][1] == 'x' ||   // Check col 1
                    board[0][2] == 'x' && board[1][2] == 'x' && board[2][2] == 'x' ||   // Check col 2
                    board[0][0] == 'x' && board[1][1] == 'x' && board[2][2] == 'x' ||   // Check diag \
                    board[0][2] == 'x' && board[1][1] == 'x' && board[2][0] == 'x')     // Check diag /


            {
                return 'X';
            }
            else if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[0][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O' ||  // Check row 0
                    board[1][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' ||   // Check row 1
                    board[2][0] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O' ||   // Check row 2
                    board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][0] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O' ||   // Check col 0
                    board[0][1] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' ||   // Check col 1
                    board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O' ||   // Check col 2
                    board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O' ||   // Check diag \
                    board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O' ||   // Check diag /

                    board[0][0] == 'o' && board[0][1] == 'o' && board[0][2] == 'o' ||   // Check row 0
                    board[1][0] == 'o' && board[1][1] == 'o' && board[1][2] == 'o' ||   // Check row 1
                    board[2][0] == 'o' && board[2][1] == 'o' && board[2][2] == 'o' ||   // Check row 2
                    board[0][0] == 'o' && board[1][0] == 'o' && board[2][0] == 'o' ||   // Check col 0
                    board[0][1] == 'o' && board[1][1] == 'o' && board[2][1] == 'o' ||   // Check col 1
                    board[0][2] == 'o' && board[1][2] == 'o' && board[2][2] == 'o' ||   // Check col 2
                    board[0][0] == 'o' && board[1][1] == 'o' && board[2][2] == 'o' ||   // Check diag \
                    board[0][2] == 'o' && board[1][1] == 'o' && board[2][0] == 'o')     // Check diag /

            {
                return 'O';
            }

            boolean finished = true;

            // If there is a blank space in the board, the game isn't finished yet
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < board[ i ].length; j++)
                    if (board[ i ][ j ] == ' ')
                        finished = false;

            // If the board is finished and 'X' or 'O' wasn't returned, then it is a tie
            // Otherwise, the game is not finished yet
            if ( finished )
                return 'T';
            else
                return 'N';
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

> // Get the location from the user and validate it

It looks like you are already doing this in the preceding lines:

```
// you're validating the input here
while (x < 0 && x >2 && y <0 && y > 2)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the row and column, separated by spaces: ");
    // you're getting the location from the user here
    x = in.nextInt();
    y = in.nextInt();
}
```

You probably still need to check to see if the position the user entered is a position that's already been filled in. You need to look in the array for that. There's a comment in `moveAI` giving you a hint for this. You check if `board[x][y]` is a space.

Also, I think you have a bug there because you never reset the values for `x` and `y`, so the next time the player's turn comes around the loop will not be entered. `x` and `y` still have the last turn's values so the loop condition evaluates to `false`. I think you can solve this problem by using a `do{...}while(...);` loop instead of a `while(...){...}` loop.

> // Mark the position in the board according to the user's specified location

This just means put an `'O'` in `board[x][y]`.

> // Check to see if the game is finished. If it is, break out of the loop.

It looks like `checkWinner` does this. It returns `'T'` if the game is done and `'N'` if it's still going.

---

For the AI code, here is some pseudocode for what I think you should be doing:

```
1. generate random x, y coordinates
2. check if board[x][y] is already used (there's a comment that tells how)
3. if it's used, go back to 1, otherwise put an 'X' in that space and return
```

Also, you don't need the loops that check for `while (x < 0 && x >2 && y < 0 && y > 2)` in the AI code. `Random.nextInt(3)` already returns a number in the range `0-2`.